# Sourcing all files from a directory which may have same procedure and variable names

Tags: tcl

I am a newbie in TCL Programming.
I have tons of files in a directory and I want to source them all. But the problem is, there are many files containing same variable name. So how to resolve this conflict and how to access variables separately using file name.
I am thinking of using namespaces, what would be the right way to accomplish this task.

In python I can use fileName.variable after importing it. Is there any way to do that in TCL.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using namespaces is a good approach

```
foreach file [glob *.tcl] {
    set ns [file rootname $file]   ;# remove ".tcl" extension
    namespace eval $ns {source $file}
}
```

Testing

```
$ cat a.tcl
set hello world
proc foo {} {return bar}

$ tclsh
% set file a.tcl
a.tcl
% set ns [file rootname $file]
a
% namespace eval $ns {source $file}
% puts $hello
can't read "hello": no such variable
% puts $a::hello
world
% foo
invalid command name "foo"
% a::foo
bar
```

Comment: Thank You for the help. I want to create all these namespaces in a proc. But then these namespaces would be local to that procedure. How to make them global to access outside.

Comment: `proc create {ns file} {namespace eval $ns [list source $file]}`

Comment: I just want to pass directory name to proc and it will source all files from that directory. And I want to make list of those namespaces and make it global so that I can access this list to iterate through them and process containing variables. My code `proc sourceFiles {dir} \
{
 
 set files [glob -directory $dir *] 
    foreach f $files {
    set ns [file tail [file rootname [file rootname $f]]]   ;# remove ".tcl" and ".txt" extensions
 
        namespace eval $ns { source $f} ;# creating namespace for each file 
}
}`

Comment: But its showing error in last line. 'f' variable not found. I dont understand what's wrong.

Comment: Do what I did in my last comment: change `{source $f}` to `[list source $f]`

Comment: yeah, it's working now. Can you please elaborate? How making list working and not the prior command. Thanks!